# Sql query for distinct values without sorting for a single table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have only one database table and i need to get a distinct value without sorting?

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblFormsData](
[fieldID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[fieldName] [varchar](200) NULL,
[fieldValue] [varchar](max) NULL,
[formType] [int] NULL,
[instantID] [varchar](10) NULL,
[dateCreated] [datetime] NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_tblFormsData] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
(
[fieldID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

input field name column

```
---------------------------
Name 
CPR number
Address
Mobile
Name 
CPR number
Address
Mobile
```

output field name column

```
----------------------------
Address
CPR Number
Mobile
Name
```

output i need field name column

```
--------------------------------
Name
CPR Number
Address
Mobile
```

Comment: do you have any auto_increment or identity keys on the table?

Comment: Can you provide a little more information on what you've done?  You state you have "output", but you haven't provided any SQL that currently produces it.  Alternatively, maybe the clue's in the question you asked - look up "DISTINCT" - unless you mean "particular", rather than "distinct".

Comment: Why is this tagged with two databases?  Which are you really using, MySQL or SQL Server?  What is the name of the table?  What is the name of the column?  Are there any other columns in the table?

Comment: CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblFormsData](
[fieldID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[fieldName] [varchar](200) NULL,
[fieldValue] [varchar](max) NULL,
[formType] [int] NULL,
[instantID] [varchar](10) NULL,
[dateCreated] [datetime] NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_tblFormsData] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
(
[fieldID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] 

this is the table

 select distinct fieldName from tblFormsData where formType=2
 this is the query

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please put table defns in your question, by editing it. They are very hard to read in comments.

Answer (score 2):

```
select fieldName
from tblFormsData
group by fieldName
order by min(fieldID)
```